# MSSDK doesn't build

Tags: actionscript-3, kinect

I'm trying to use Kinect on Windows with AS3. So I've download the MS SDK and add the .ane to my project (FlashDevelop).

Here my main.as :

```
public function Main()
        {
            stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
            stage.align  = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
            trace(Kinect.isSupported());
            if (Kinect.isSupported())
            {
                _kinect = Kinect.getDevice();

                var deviceSettings : MSKinectSettings = new MSKinectSettings();
                deviceSettings.userMaskEnabled = false;
                deviceSettings.depthShowUserColors = false;
                deviceSettings.depthResolution = CameraResolution.RESOLUTION_640_480;
                deviceSettings.rgbResolution = CameraResolution.RESOLUTION_640_480;
                deviceSettings.rgbEnabled = true;

                _kinect.start( deviceSettings );

                _kinect.addEventListener( DeviceEvent.STARTED, kinectStartedHandler, false, 0, true );
                _kinect.addEventListener( DeviceEvent.STOPPED, kinectStoppedHandler, false, 0, true );
                _kinect.addEventListener( CameraImageEvent.RGB_IMAGE_UPDATE, rgbImageUpdateHandler, false, 0, true );
                _kinect.addEventListener( UserEvent.USERS_ADDED, _userAdded, false, 0, true );
                _kinect.addEventListener( UserEvent.USERS_UPDATED, _userUpdated, false, 0, true );
                _kinect.addEventListener( UserEvent.USERS_REMOVED, _userRemoved, false, 0, true );
                _kinect.addEventListener( DeviceInfoEvent.INFO, onDeviceInfo, false, 0, true );
                _kinect.addEventListener( DeviceErrorEvent.ERROR, onDeviceError, false, 0, true );

                addChild( _bmp = new Bitmap());
            }
        }
```

When I run the app, i've got the following error :

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at com.as3nui.nativeExtensions.air.kinect.bridge::ExtensionContextBridge()
    at com.as3nui.nativeExtensions.air.kinect.manager::KinectManager/get sharedBridge()
    at com.as3nui.nativeExtensions.air.kinect.manager::KinectManager()
    at com.as3nui.nativeExtensions.air.kinect.manager::KinectManager$/getInstance()
    at com.as3nui.nativeExtensions.air.kinect::Kinect$/get kinectManager()
    at com.as3nui.nativeExtensions.air.kinect::Kinect$/isSupported()
    at Main()
    at runtime::ContentPlayer/loadInitialContent()
    at runtime::ContentPlayer/playRawContent()
    at runtime::ContentPlayer/playContent()
```

I've been searching on ASNui Forum and it seems to be a driver issue. However i've checked all the file, reboot my pc and nothing change...

Moreover, if I unplug the Kinect, i've got the same error message.

thx for helping

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run an application in debug mode with an ane, you have to unpack the extension, and run it with the -extdir  argument, with path pointing to the directory which contains the unpacked.ane folder.